# Unable to partially compare two Jsons in Karate framework

Tags: java, json, karate

I've to compare 2 Jsons,

Json A

```
{
ele:[
{
id:1,
name:'abc'
},
{
id:2,
name:'def'
..
{
id:100,
name:'xyxxz'
}
]
}
```

Json B

```
{
ele:[
{
id:1,
name:'abc'
},
{
id:2,
name:'def'
..
{
id:10,
name:'xxx'
}
]
}
```

I wish to partially compare the jsons. When i tried with match-contains it Fails.
Kindly suggest a way to partial compare the json.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
* def json = { ele: [{ id: 1, name: 'abc' }, { id: 2, name: 'def' }, { id: 10, name: 'xxx' }] }
* match json.ele contains [{ id: 1, name: 'abc' }, { id: 2, name: 'def' }]
```